a.InsertedDate>= dateadd(hh,-1,getdate())
In salesforce marketing cloud, I have an InsertedDate field that is a date format field. The values look like this: Nov 16 2024 10:45AM. I am in eastern time zone.
I am trying to only select records from the past 1 hour. I am using this sql, but I keep getting back results from the last 2 hours instead of 1 hour:
a.InsertedDate>= dateadd(hh,-1,getdate())
Can anyone help solve this, could it be related to timezones?
a.InsertedDate>= dateadd(hh,-1,getdate()) expecting to get results back from the past hour.

The server may be set for a different time zone. Check that getdate() returns the expected value.

GetDate() in SFMC will always return US Central Time no DST.

You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at salesforce.stackexchange.com, specifically with the marketing-cloud and query tags.

Which dbms are you using? dateadd and getdate are product specific functions.
